# Access Photos of IPhone Automatically in java

Tags: java, iphone, windows, directory, photo-gallery

I want to get the photos from IPhone folders  in my Java Application  when an iphone is attached to pc.But I could not any Help ? Please suggest me some idea to do this task .I searched a lot but could not find useful way to do that task .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the code `new File("Apple IPhone")` will not open your iphone's storage - you need to find a java API which can talk to the phone via itunes (this probably does not exist). File class in java is used to access the PC's local storage e.g. `new File("c://windows")` will create a reference to the 'windows' folder in c: drive